# How can I set up global for every imported file in Python automatically?

Tags: python, module, import

I have a large python code with many modules and classes. I have a special class, whose single instance is needed everywhere throughout the code (it's a threaded application, and that instance of a class also holds Thread Local Storage, locks, etc). It's a bit uncomfortable to always "populate" that instance in every imported module. I know, using globals is not the best practice, but anyway: is there any "import hook" in python, so I can do with hooking on it to have my instance available in every modules without extra work? It should work for normal imports, "from mod import ..." too, and for **import** constructs too. If this is not possible, can you suggest a better solution? Certenly it's not fun to pass that instance to the constructors of every classes, etc ... Inheritance also does not help, since I have modules without classes, and also I need a single instance, not the class itself ...

```
class master():
    def import_module(self, name):
        mod = __import__(name)
        mod.m = self
        return mod
[...]
m = master()
```

Currently I am thinking something like that: but then I have to use m.import_module() to import modules, then other modules will have instance of master class with name of "m" available, so I can use m.import_module() too, etc. But then I have to give up to use "normal" import statements, and I should write this:

```
example_mod = m.module_import("example_mod")
```

instead of just this:

```
import example_mod
```

(but for sure I can do with this too, to assign "m" to example_mod.m then)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Certainly it's not fun to pass that instance to the constructors of
>   every classes

You don't have to do this. Set up your global class in a module like `config` and import it

```
# /myapp/enviroment/__init__.py

class ThatSingleInstanceClass: pass

# create the singleton object directly or have a function init the module
singleton = ThatSingleInstanceClass() 



# /myapp/somewhere.py

# all you need to use the object is importing it
from myapp.enviroment import singleton

class SomeClass:

    def __init__(self): # no need to pass that object
        print "Always the same object:", singleton
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It seems I still have to learn a lot, before this I would have guessed that importing the instace results different instances, but I understand well now, if a module is imported, that namespace is used, even if it's imported from another module then, so it won't be a new one. Just I am curious if it's dirty enough if I have my class name master, then I make an instance with name master [so, the same name] :) So after that, no other modules can import the class itself by mistake, just the instance :) It works for me anyway.

Comment: @LGB: If you follow pep8 (you should), you'd name your class `Master` (classes use PascalCase in python), and then there's no conflict with a `master` instance -- except to say that you should pick a more meaningful variable name? How do people use the variable? Name it that.

Answer (score 2):

What's wrong with having each module import the needed object? Explicit is better than implicit.

Comment: Well, that's ugly too, since that instance is used a lot, so I want to put it into the global namespace of the imported mod, so I don't need to write "self" every time then: if I pass the instance of my "master" class to the constructor of a class in an imported module, the ugly hack needed for this to say "global m" and then "m = m_in" where m_in is a parameter for the constructor. The other solution is to put into the class' namespace, but then I have to use it in other methods as "self.something". As python has some globals too like sorted(), I'd like to have my "m" as a global everywhere.

Comment: See @Jochen Ritzel's answer. That's the sort of thing I meant.

Comment: Ok, sorry, I totally misunderstood. I agree, just - it seems - I had problems understaing python importing in details :)